# Is it possible to use only the data package of ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Very simple doubt.

I like the ExtJS data package, specially the stores and their restful synchronizable stores, but i don't like programming the visual part with extjs.

It is possible to import only these components to use within other visual stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with [Sencha CMD](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/extjs/cmd_app.html).

What happens is that when you call `sencha app build` you get a production build file called "app.js" containing only the classes that your application needs (and their dependencies). So, basically you can just create a dummy class for the purpose of including what you want in the build only:

```
Ext.define('Dummy', {
    uses: [
        'Ext.data.Store'
        // other stuff you need
    ]
});
```

Then you simply include the "app.js" file in the page and use the data package whatever way you want.

Comment: I understood the concept, but not really how I'm gonna do that. If I just do a `senhca app build` in a empty project (after `sencha generate app`) I get a 727Kb app.js. The ideia here would be to have a file that only contains the classes specified and their dependencies.